# How can I redirect to a thank you page in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, contacts

Ok, so I would like to redirect to a thank you page after completion of my contact form.  Right now, it's just a plain, unstyled thank you, and I would like it to redirect to a page that I've desiged called contact-thank-you.html

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="form_processor.php" method="post" >
        Name:<br /><input type="text" name="name" required="required" /><br /><br />
        E-mail:<br /><input type="text" name="email" required="required" /><br /><br />
        Message:<br /><textarea name="message" required="required"></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is form_processor.php:

```
    $to      = 'myemail@email.com';
$subject = "New Message From Your Website";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <myemail@email.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: myemail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Thank you, you message has been sent!";
```

Comment: Note: Kaii's answer is the way to go, but you'll have to take out the `echo` at the end in order to use this and insert the thank you message inside `contact-thank-you.html`. You can't use echo and header at the same time, far as I know.

Answer (score 10):

remove `echo "Thank you, you message has been sent!";`

because it won`t be necessary to have it since your redirecting your page
then use this after all the transaction in finish to redirect

```
header('Location: contact-thank-you.html');
exit();
```

And Create a nice *Thank You Template* on you `contact-thank-you.html`

Resources:

php.net: [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: This is the way to go, but you cannot have ANY output above this header and should usually follow this line with an `exit;`  -- any output above this header will throw an error.

Comment: you can't echo in an .html file, unless you modify .htaccess to let it behave as a .php ;-)

Comment: @Fred another great resource . have never tried before.. thanks.!

Answer (score 4):

replace:

```
echo "Thank you, you message has been sent!";
```

with:

```
header('Location: contact-thank-you.html');
exit;
```

**reference**

- [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from html page to another page like php page then just write this code it will work for you

```
<?php  
  header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ; 
   //or 
  header( 'Location: nextpage.php' ) ; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: contact-thank-you.html');
```

This should be the answer that you are looking for(:

You can refer to here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

header('Location: thank-you.php');

or u can echo massage (ajax message on same place)

```
if(@mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
     {
    echo "<p class='ajax_success'>Thanks for Contact Us.</p>";
     }
     else
     {
     echo "<p class='ajax_failure'>Sorry, Try again Later.</p>";
     }
```

and here ajax validation;

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Main Contact Form...
    jQuery("#frmcontact").validate(
    { 
        //Onblur Validation...
        onfocusout: function(element)
        {   
            $(element).valid();
        },         
        rules:
        { 
          txtname:
          {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
          },
          txtemail:
          {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },          
         txtphone:
          {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
          },
         txtenquiry:
          {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
          }       
        }
    });
    //Ajax Submit...
    $('#frmcontact').submit(function () {
    if($('#txtname').is('.valid') && $('#txtemail').is('.valid') && $('#txtphone').is('.valid') && $('#txtenquiry').is('.valid')) {

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#ajax_message").slideUp(750, function () {
            $('#ajax_message').hide();

            $.post(action, {
                name: $('#txtname').val(),
                email: $('#txtemail').val(),
                phone: $('#txtphone').val(),                
                comment: $('#txtenquiry').val()
            }, function (data) {
                document.getElementById('ajax_message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#ajax_message').slideDown('slow');
                if (data.match('success') != null) $('#frmcontact').slideUp('slow');
            });
        });
      }
      return false;     
    });

and lucks very good
```